# add two or more numbers using a turing machine emulator

Tags: turing-machines

I'm playing around with a turing machine emulator and I'm trying to add more than two numbers together. I can make it add two numbers together and halt, but I cant make it halt if I add 3 or more numbers (eg 4+3+3 will not halt after adding the last number instead it continues for ever).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eyZd.png - if this doesn't work I can trying something else.

This is what I have, I'm just not sure what I need to do. Any help is appreciated, if you need more information don't hesitate to ask

Cheers

Comment: May 2 digit numbers occupy 1 slot? what algorithm are you using to add the numbers?

Comment: As you don't seem to have the option of writing arbitrary values to the tape, this looks more like Post's machine. If this is the case, you should provide details on the number encoding you're using.

Comment: I can write numbers on the tape in form of 1's with a blank between then to signify the number, I'll update the image to show this. I'm not exactly sure how different this emulator is to what you guys are familiar with, but it's just one that was supplied to me by my Uni.